# Working with strings in lists (Python Sentiment Analysis)

Tags: python, string, sentiment-analysis

I like to do a small sentiment analysis about hotel reviews.

Example (stop_word_filter:

['Even', 'though', 'pictures', 'show', 'clean', 'rooms', 'actual', 'room', 'quit', 'dirty', 'outlived', 'Also', 'check', '15', 'clock', 'room', 'not', 'ready', 'time']

I figured out that this is about a "hotelroom" and about "clean". I want to connect now the closes "negative" word to "clean"which should be "dirty". 
I integrated a list of negative words. 
I am hanging on the implementation...

Code:

```
bullets = [] #output
distances = []
bad_word_locations = []
rubrik_word_location = [] #category_word

#if there is a category word in the review

if len(rubrik_uR_list) == 1:

    #get the index of that one 
        rubrik_word_location = stop_words_filter.index(rubrik_uR_list[0])

        #go throu all negative words and if one of them in my sentence get the index of that word
        for w in negativ_words_list:  
            if w in stop_words_filter:
                bad_word_locations.append(stop_words_filter.index(w)) 

            #NOW ITS GETTING CRUCIAL 
            #if we found one 
            if len(bad_word_locations) > 0:

                #I need to some how catch now the closest word, my code is not doing this
                distances.append(abs(rubrik_word_location-bad_word_locations[0])) 

                bullets.append(stop_words_filter[min(distances)])

                #if I got more categories in one review I need to remind that somehow...
                blacklist.append(stop_words_filter[min(distances)])
```

I am poor in programming, I see.
I would appreciate your help faithfully.

Thanks in advance, Niklas

Answer (score 0):

I just could figure it out myself.

```
def getBulletPoint(pos_filter,stop_words_filter, rubrik_uR_list):      

    index_of_category_word = 0
    distance = 0
    count = 0 

    #Finde alle negaive Wörter 
    for w in negativ_words_list:             
        if w in stop_words_filter:
            bad_words.append(w) 

    #finde die Indexe der negativen Wörter        
    for w in bad_words:
        word_index.append(stop_words_filter.index(w))

    if len(rubrik_uR_list) > 0 and len(bad_words) > 0 : #Wenn wir überhaupt ein Rubrikwort haben



#-------------Loop-------------------                
        for w in rubrik_uR_list:     

            saved_distance = 1000 

#            bullets.append(rubrik_list[count])
#            bullets.append(rubrik_uR_list[count])

            index_of_category_word = stop_words_filter.index(rubrik_uR_list[count])

            for i in word_index:
                distance = abs(i-index_of_category_word)

                if distance < saved_distance:
                    current_bullet = (stop_words_filter[i])
                    saved_distance = distance

            bullets.append(current_bullet)

            count = count + 1
```

Best regards, Niklas